# To find all emails on a page

Tags: javascript, html

I want to have JavaScript/jQuery code that scan a whole page looking for emails and stores them in an array.

I have a regular expression for email and I know how to check if lets say a textfield has a valid email BUT I have no idea how to scan whole document/page (h1 tags, h2 tags, anchor tags.....) looking for email. Please help

Comment: You could get the whole body content, string it and then use a regex to get all the e-mails are actually written in the body.

Comment: Could you give me some more info about: "get the whole body content and string it" Some code samples would be great

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i think this is what you are looking for:

```
 function getEmails() {

var search_in = document.body.innerHTML;
string_context = search_in.toString();

array_mails = string_context.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi);
return array_mails;

}
```

Short explanation:
This function just gets the content of the body, where e-mails should be, makes it a string and then uses a simple regex to get all the matches (/g modifier is applied), case-insensitive (/i modifier is also), that sounds like e-mail text. Then these matches are returned as an array of all of them. `var my_emails = getEmails()` could be your wondered array.

Comment: Ok I am JS NOOB so: document.body.innerHTML;  it has all page elemnts? Then I cast it to Strings and If it mach the RE then I add it to array ? yes ?

Comment: look at my explanation so:

Comment: body contents is where e-mails you are looking for are likely written. yes then my edit covers the other answers. yes

Comment: OK I think I get it, thnx very much. More important question - how did you acquire such a knowledge ? Where should I start ? :)

Comment: please don't exaggerate ahah! I think if you are here you found a great place to start, another resource i can deeply advise is www.google.com and lots of queries to input by your fancy.

Comment: this is not working in 2023

Comment: I am getting NULL

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to find **email addresses** in the source code you can take the whole `body` of the page and parse them out directly with the `match()` method.

```
// assuming you have your regex stored in a variable "regex"
var emails = document.body.match(regex);
for(var i=0; i<emails.length; i++){
    console.log(emails[i]); // or whatever you need to do with them
}
```

Comment: Ok I'll check out this solution too thnx for help

Comment: can you share the regex code